# If $\lim\limits_{z \to \infty} |F(z)|=0$, can $\lim\limits_{z \to \infty} F(z) \ne 0$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits, proof-explanation

To prove the existence of limit of $F(z)$ at $z=\infty$ in [here](http://www.irjes.com/Papers/vol2-issue2/Vesion%202/C222529.pdf) (Eq. 1.8 page 3) it says that since $\lim\limits_{z \to \infty} |F(z)|=0$ thus $\lim\limits_{z \to \infty} F(z)=w_n$ exists; Of course exits, but also must $w_n=0$. But Nor this article neither the book Churchill Sec 117 Exercise 2 doesn't say $w_n=0$. Can $w_n \ne 0$ be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit must be zero. Suppose $\lim F(z)=w_n$ exists. Then $\lim | F(z)-w_n |=0$. However $|F(z)-w_n| \geq \big||F(z)|-|w_n| \big|$, for any $z$ by the triangle inequality, so it follows that $\lim \big||F(z)|-|w_n| \big|=0$. That is, $\lim |F(z)|=|w_n|$.

Note that the convergence of $|F(z)|$ does not imply $F(z)$ converges unless $\lim |F(z)|=0$.

Comment: $w_n=F(\infty)$ for Schwarz-Christoffel transformations which is not zero always. That's why I am confused!

Comment: Honestly I think the document you linked is not terribly well written.The appearance of individual equations is messy, the spacing is all over the place, the alignment is bad. e.g. in equation 1.6 half of the equation is centered and half is not. The exponents are very far from the terms they exponetiate. Work like this is hard to follow, both for the reader and the author, and it leaves room for the author to have made a mistake. In equatioin 1.8 the author bounds the limit of $F(z)$ above by zero and uses that to conclude that $F(z)$ converges to some value.

Comment: There are two problems there. First, the author hasn't shown that the limit has a lower bound, so from what is shown they cannot conclude a limit exists. Now the equations can easily be applied to $-F(z)$ to get that the limit is bounded below by zero, but they should have at least commented on this. Now if the limit is both bounded above and below by zero then the limit must be zero. So why do they say it converges to some value and not emphasize zero? I didn't carefully check the details in the document, but I wouldn't trust what is written in without checking extremely carefully.

Comment: I also found that the journal which published the article you linked is on the predatory journal list found at https://predatoryjournals.com/journals/#I. In short, you should not trust that article or anything from that journal.